# Read SQLite database with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, ecmascript-6, node-sqlite3

Having this SQLite DB I'm trying to read the data from it. So, from table Athlete I want to read the first 3 columns.

[image]

This is the code (app.js):

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('ocs_athletes');

db.serialize(function () {
  db.each('SELECT athlete_id, name, surname FROM Athlete', function (err, row) {
    console.log('User: ', row.athlete_id, row.name, row.surname);
  });
});

db.close();
```

The file app.js is in the same folder as the db file - ocs_athletes.

Running in cmd `node app.js` returns this error message:

```
/home/dd/Documents/Projects/OCSapp/app.js:6
    console.log('User: ', row.athlete_id, row.name, row.surname);
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'athlete_id' of undefined
    at /home/dd/Documents/Projects/OCSapp/app.js:6:31
    at replacement (/home/dd/Documents/Projects/OCSapp/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:25:27)
    at Statement.errBack (/home/dd/Documents/Projects/OCSapp/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:14:21)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Why to use `db. serialize` ?

Comment: I don't know, it's the first time I'm using SQLite with Node and this is how I've found in a tutorial. should I do it differently?

Comment: As I can see in documentation. The `each()` method executes an SQL query with specified parameters and calls a callback for every row in the result set.. What do you want to do get all rows or specific rows ?

Comment: doesn't matter, all of them are fine. I was looking at this tutorial and did it like that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCuJi2kzaqI

Comment: Have just tried printing just `row` what data you are getting in return.

Comment: it returns `undefined`

Comment: I guess it is not connecting to the DB file but don't know why

Comment: Yes that is problem I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try connecting to db like this.

```
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./ocs_athlete.db', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log('Connected to the my database.');
});
```

Give path of `.db` file. This will work.

There are three opening modes:

`sqlite3.OPEN_READONLY`: open the database for read-only.

`sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE` : open the database for reading and writting.

`sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE`: open the database, if the database does not exist, create a new database.

To open the chinook sample database for read and write, you can do it as follows:

```
let db = new sqlite3.Database('./ocs_athlete.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log('Connected to the ocs_athlete database.');
});
```